# How to change element name 'ArrayOfResponse' in Soap XML WCF services

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, service

My problem How to change The ArrayOfResponse Element in SOAP XML WCF services
using Message class.... see image I want change the element in red box ....
any ideas ???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqtzz.png)

that my code to get this result !

my interface

```
[ServiceContract()]
    public interface IEvaluationWebService
    {
        [OperationContract(ReplyAction = "Evaluations")]
        Message GetEvaluations(EvaluationRequest evaluationRequest);
    }
```

this method tasks one parameter EvaluationRequest class ,to return Message ( List of Evaluation class )

```
Message IEvaluationWebService.GetEvaluations(EvaluationRequest evaluationRequest)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("");

        DateTime dtstart = new DateTime();
        DateTime.TryParseExact(evaluationRequest.PeriodStart, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out dtstart);
        evaluationRequest.PeriodStart = dtstart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        DateTime dtend = new DateTime();
        DateTime.TryParseExact(evaluationRequest.PeriodEnd, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out dtend);
        evaluationRequest.PeriodEnd = dtend.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetEmployeeEvaluation", cnn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PeriodStart", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = evaluationRequest.PeriodStart;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PeriodEnd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = evaluationRequest.PeriodEnd;

        cnn.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<Evaluation> evaluationList = new List<Evaluation>();

        MessageVersion ver = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageVersion;
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation();
            evaluation.EstLaborOfficeId = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["EstLaborOfficeId"].ToString());
            evaluation.EstSequenceNumber = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["EstSequenceNumber"].ToString());
            evaluation.IdNumber = 
            evaluationList.Add(evaluation);
        }
        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation();
        cnn.Close();
        return Message.CreateMessage(ver, "Evaluations", evaluationList);
    }
```

The request class to passing the dates for method and gets data ....

```
        [MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "GetEvaluation", WrapperNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
public class EvaluationRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public string PeriodStart { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 2)]
    public string PeriodEnd { get; set; }
}
```

request class(the parameters for GetEvaluations method )

```
        [MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "GetEvaluation", WrapperNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
public class EvaluationRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public string PeriodStart { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 2)]
    public string PeriodEnd { get; set; }
}
```

Evaluation class

```
        [DataContract()]
    public class Evaluation
    {
        private int _EstLaborOfficeId;
        private int _EstSequenceNumber;
        private long _IdNumber;

        [DataMember]
        public int EstLaborOfficeId
        {
            get { return _EstLaborOfficeId; }
            set { _EstLaborOfficeId = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public int EstSequenceNumber
        {
            get { return _EstSequenceNumber; }
            set { _EstSequenceNumber = value; }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone, who wants to consume your service, does not know what kind of result he will reveice. It is just "Message" and has not specific MessageContract.

As far as I can see from here, you want to give back a list of Evaluation.

What you could try is this: (Untested)

```
[MessageContract]
public class Evaluation
{
    private int _EstLaborOfficeId;
    private int _EstSequenceNumber;
    private long _IdNumber;

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public int EstLaborOfficeId
    {
        get { return _EstLaborOfficeId; }
        set { _EstLaborOfficeId = value; }
    }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public int EstSequenceNumber
    {
        get { return _EstSequenceNumber; }
        set { _EstSequenceNumber = value; }
    }
}



[MessageContract]
public class EvaluationList
{
     [MessageBodyMember]
     public List<Evaluation> Values {get;set}
}


[ServiceContract()]
public interface IEvaluationWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    EvaluationList GetEvaluations(EvaluationRequest evaluationRequest);
}
```

...or just try use List as return and forget EvaluationList.

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IEvaluationWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Evaluation> GetEvaluations(EvaluationRequest evaluationRequest);
}
```

Now, EvaluationList and EvaluationRequest are both MessageContracts.

**Please keep in mind, that you ONLY want to use MessageContract, if you want full control of the SOAP Message. This does not seem to be the case here.**

So, the more easy way would be, to change your EvaluationRequest back to DataContract:

```
[DataContract()]
public class Evaluation
{
    private int _EstLaborOfficeId;
    private int _EstSequenceNumber;
    private long _IdNumber;

    [DataMember]
    public int EstLaborOfficeId
    {
        get { return _EstLaborOfficeId; }
        set { _EstLaborOfficeId = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public int EstSequenceNumber
    {
        get { return _EstSequenceNumber; }
        set { _EstSequenceNumber = value; }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class EvaluationRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PeriodStart { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PeriodEnd { get; set; }
} 

[ServiceContract()]
public interface IEvaluationWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Evaluation> GetEvaluations(EvaluationRequest evaluationRequest);
}
```

**The GOLDEN RULE IS:** Try not to mix DataContract and MessageContract in a service operation, because WCF will see this as security flaw.

So define **BOTH** classes, result **AND** parameter, as DataContract **OR** MessageContract, but don't mix it up.